# Get a thumbnail URL for an image in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, image, thumbnail

I am trying to return an URL of my image, but an error appears on the console tab:

> Line 100: Setting the CRS, geodesic, or evenOdd flag on a computed
> Geometry is not supported.  Use Geometry.transform()

How can I do this?

```
var image2020 = GPW.filterDate ('2020-01-01','2020-12-31')
          .first (); print (image2020);
          
var image2000 = GPW.filterDate ('2000-01-01','2000-12-31')
          .first (); print (image2000);
          
var irant = gaul.filterMetadata ('ADM0_CODE', 'equals', 117 ); 
print (irant);
Map.setCenter (52.71, 34.62, 4);
Map.addLayer (irant, {}, 'Iran Territory', false);          

var raster_vis = {
  "max": 100,
  "palette": [
    "F3E9EE",
    "DBBDCC",
    "C392AB",
    "9F5178",
    "79224E",
    "841F2F"
  ],
  "min": 0.0
};

var iranp2020 = image2020.clipToCollection (irant);
var iranp2000 = image2000.clipToCollection (irant);

Map.setCenter (52.71, 34.62, 5);
Map.addLayer (iranp2020, raster_vis, 'Iran Urbanization Map 2020');
Map.addLayer (iranp2000, raster_vis, 'Iran Urbanization Map 2000');

// set position of panel
var legend = ui.Panel({
style: {
position: 'bottom-left',
padding: '8px 15px'
}
});

// Create legend title
var legendTitle = ui.Label({
value: 'Iran Urbanization Map 2020 (P/km2)',
style: {
fontWeight: 'bold',
fontSize: '18px',
margin: '0 0 4px 0',
padding: '0'
}
});

// Add the title to the panel
legend.add(legendTitle);

// create the legend image
var lon = ee.Image.pixelLonLat().select('latitude');
var gradient = lon.multiply((raster_vis.max-raster_vis.min)/100.0).add(raster_vis.min);
var legendImage = gradient.visualize(raster_vis);


// create text on top of legend
var panel = ui.Panel({
widgets: [
ui.Label(raster_vis['max'])
],
});

legend.add(panel);

// create thumbnail from the image
var thumbnail = ui.Thumbnail({
image: legendImage,
params: {bbox:'0,0,10,100', dimensions:'10x200'},
style: {padding: '1px', position: 'bottom-center'}
});

// add the thumbnail to the legend
legend.add(thumbnail);

// create text on top of legend
var panel = ui.Panel({
widgets: [
ui.Label(raster_vis['min'])
],
});

legend.add(panel);
Map.add(legend);

var viz = {
  min: 0,
  max: 100,
  format: "png",
  region: irant,
  'crs': 'EPSG:32638'
};

print (viz);
print (iranp2000.getThumbURL(viz));
```

Comment: Could you please share the code link?

Comment: Sure ...
https://code.earthengine.google.com/?scriptPath=users%2Ftaghdisian90%2FCode_practicing%3AIRAN_GPW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem too. And I solved it by transferring the region variable from `Feature` or `FeatureCollection` into geometry in the video visualization parameter.

In you case, maybe you can try it in the last part of you code:

```js
var viz = {
  min: 0,
  max: 100,
  format: "png",
  region: irant.geometry(),
  'crs': 'EPSG:32638'
};
```

I hope it can help.